# Assigning an empty binary value to a varbinary(MAX) column creates a column 8000 bytes long

Tags: sql, t-sql, varbinary, varbinarymax

I have a table with a varbinary(max) column, i am trying to assign to that column a zero-lengh binary buffer, but instead of getting a zero-length value in the table, i am getting an 8000 bytes long value filled with zeros:
[image: 8000 long zero buffer]
* the dataSize column in the shown query was added using DATALENGHT(data) ("SELECT _index, **dataSize=DATALENGHT(data)**, data FROM....") and shows the actual size on the table of the value

Where does the 8000 bytes long empty buffer come from? is this some kind of default behavior?

Comment: How was the assignment of the zero-length buffer performed? What technologies were involved (i.e. was this from some piece of client code somewhere)?

Answer (score 0):

If your source column is binary(8000), then `DATALENGTH(data)` will return 8000 (it is fully padded) and data will contain the full 8000 bytes.

But since you are using

```
SELECT _index, dataSize=DATALENGTH(data), data FROM
```

It cannot be a binary(8000) column - because a fixed size column will report the same datalength for all rows.  It is likely some data was copied there from a `BINARY(8000)` variable or other means some time in the past.

Comment: I can assure you no data was copied, the presented row is a result of an UPDATE query assigning a zero-sized buffer to the data column- i check the contents before and after the query and made sure this is the case

Comment: @Amit you could have defined a client-side parameter of binary(8000) or some such, and even if you give it a value of 0-size buffer, the db driver will pad out to 8000. The long and short is the data is there in the table where you are doing the SELECT..FROM

Comment: @Richard i'm not sure i understand the second part of your comment, could you please clarify?

Comment: @Amit - this part? `The long and short is the data is there in the table where you are doing the SELECT..FROM` It means that you need to track down how it got in there, but it is surely in the table right now (a record-column-data with 8000 bytes).

Comment: @Richard it's obviously in the table.. but as far as i could track it down, the query i sent was valid, i am using the .Net internal SQL client class